# Compile files with certain pattern names in ANT

Tags: ant, build

I need to compile a set of files say they have a pattern "*_modules.F" (fortran files). Using ant, I have a PCC compiler set up on the machine to compile such files. How would I be able to do it via ant scripts, So far I have

```
       <exec dir="ModuleDir" executable="PCC">
            <arg line="1_module.F"/>
       </exec>
```

The above would work for a single module, how can get it to work for all the module with the pattern "*_modules.F"? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [apply ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) which takes a fileset as a parameter. Without the "parallel" attribute the executable would be invoked separately for each input file.

```
<apply executable="PCC" parallel="true">
    <fileset dir="." includes="*_modules.F"/>
</apply>
```